# Text position is under Picture

Tags: css

I have a css styling problem:

I created a header with text inside. The header has two pseudo elements: `::before` and `::after`.
Both elements lay on top of the header element. How do I get the `h1` to stay in front of everything??

Here is my code example: (got code snippets removed?? i didnt found the button where to add)

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-image: url("Bild1.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 20px;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("Bild2.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-image: url("Bild3.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title Text</h1>
</header>
```

Here is a image how it looks:

[image]

As you can see the Text is behind both elements.

I tried to fix it using z-index but nothing worked for me. U have and ideas?

Comment: make your h1 position relative and give it a higher z-index that your pseudo elements (1 will do it as your pseudo elements don't have their z-index set - not sure why everyone is saying use 100)

Comment: Yes thank you! i forgot to set position relative...

Answer (score 0):

apply z-index 99 on background
and apply z-index 999 on the text I hope it will work

Comment: z-index doesn't work on non positioned elements

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the z-index of the h1 tag

```
h1{
            z-index: 999;
            color: white;
        }
```

and making the background z-index to 99 or something below that.

Comment: z-index doesn't work on non positioned elements